# Angular application showing screen blank before fully load

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, lazy-loading

Angular application on production mode with aot is taking 7-8 seconds to completely open which could be normal but during this period the entire screen is showing blank. I have added app loader to show before it gets loaded but the same is not showing on screen which gives a horrible experience.

My main*.js file is below 400kb after gzip implemetation.

On inspecting, there is a gap of around 4000ms where network is idle. I am really clueless on what is to be done.

the url to ispect is https://ayushmanbhava.org

Also, have a look at the screenshot.[image]

FYI, here is my code snippet to dig into it:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { passThruUnknownUrl: true }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: false })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true},
    fakeBackendProvider,
    AuthenticationService, CommonService, AuthGuard, AdminGuard, CookieService,
    Globals, UserService, PubService, CartService, AppInitService,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You should lazy load these images, they are taking all your initial TIME

Comment: My modules are lazy loaded, also dividing large modules into smaller chunks.

Comment: @Indrajeet can you comment on timeline between 3000ms and 8000ms idle time.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It's bit weird. There actually profiling will help you. Try to understand what is taking so much time by running diagnostics from performance tab of chrome developer console

Comment: I did the same thing and posted after thorough research. don't know why this has been downvoted 4 times. In perofmance tab, the gap is same. If it was in start I could understand it is TTFB but it is not.

Comment: I've divided this further into smaller chunks and note, total 13kb was reduced and result the same.

Comment: IDK what's going on here but seems like your view depends on something. can you put a bounty on it somebody might be attracted by it.

Comment: You seem to be using a loader, atleast make it visible. It will soften the experience in the meanwhile

Comment: My view is depend on api result and I checked both the api were called well before the white screen.

Comment: Can you share the codebase? I might be able to have a look there

Comment: *I don't know why this downvoted* you are required to provide a [mcve]. Please read the [help]

Comment: @Indrajeet I was able to get rid of this. I was running appinit service in promise which was having timeout of 6s. I did this was back and forgot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Liam I have edited this question and added code snippet, also got the answer so just wanted to add answer. Is it possible to open it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was inside this code:

```
export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}
```

function appInitService.Init() was having timeout of 6 seconds and hence it was waiting for this time to load.